# comment out the existing line and make a new entry of same line

Tags: bash, unix, text-processing

I have following line in sudoers file,

```
pankaj.a.batra      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

i need a code that could comment out this string and make a new duplicate entry with the suffix i want to add, just after this line like this

```
#pankaj.a.batra      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
pankaj.a.batra      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL su - wheel
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything? `awk` is a good choice for this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You can just go for a `sed` solution:

```
$ cat input_file.in 
a
b
c
d
ankaj.a.batra      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
e
f
g

$ SUFF=" su - wheel"; sed -i.bak "/^ankaj.a.batra      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL$/s/^\(.*\)$/#\1\n\1$SUFF/" input_file.in                            

$ cat input_file.in
a
b
c
d
#ankaj.a.batra      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
ankaj.a.batra      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL su - wheel
e
f
g
```

**Explanations:**

- `-i.bak` will activate `sed` in inline mode (modification of the input file) + backup taken of the input file just in case.
- `/^ankaj.a.batra      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL$/` will filter only lines with that contain exactly `ankaj.a.batra      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`
- On those lines, you do `s/^\(.*\)$/#\1\n\1$SUFF/` which is adding to the starting of the line a `#` and using back reference `(.*\)` to copy back the line content, create a new line, copy back this content and add the suffix.

Answer (score 0):

If [awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is an option give a try to this:

```
awk '{print "#" $0 "\n" $0}' /path/to/file
```

`"#" $0`  will comment the existing line

`"\n" $0` will make an entry of the same

In case you want to add extra text:

```
awk '{print "#" $0 "\n" $0 " su - wheel"}' foo
```

Just keep in mind that if the file has more than one line, all the "new lines" will contain `su - wheel`, so this only applies for cases when you have a file with a single line something like: `/etc/sudoers.d/pankaj.a.batra`
containing:

```
pankaj.a.batra      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

If you run:

```
awk '{print "#" $0 "\n" $0 " su - wheel"}' /etc/sudoers.d/pankaj.a.batra
```

Will print to [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams):

```
# pankaj.a.batra      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
pankaj.a.batra      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL su - wheel
```

Later if you are happy with the output you could overwrite the original file by doing something like:

```
awk '{print "#" $0 "\n" $0 " su - wheel"}' \
    /etc/sudoers.d/pankaj.a.batra > file.tmp && mv file.tmp /etc/sudoers.d/pankaj.a.batra
```

If the file has multiple lines you could try this, something that definitely could be improved as an exercise but hopefully can give you an idea:

```
 awk '
    {
        if ( $1 ~ /^pankaj.a.batra/ ) 
          { print "#" $0 "\n" $0 " su - wheel" }
        else 
          { print $0}
    }
' /etc/sudoers
```

This will check for lines that start with `pankaj.a.batra`, will comment the original line and create a new entry with your desired text, in this case `su - wheel` another way of achieving the same avoiding the if/else:

```
awk '/^pankaj.a.batra/{$0 = "#"$0"\n"$0 "su - wheel"} 1'
```

Here `1` and the end means to print every line, In awk, `$0` is the whole line of arguments, whereas `$1` is just the first argument in a list of arguments separated by spaces.